# express route wildcard both sides

Tags: node.js, express

I want each route containing the phrase Privacy to be rendered the same.

So I used http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester to make sure:
`/(.*)Privacy(.*)`
Should work.

However - the following code still gets me 404 on valid examples:

/Privacy
/aaaPrivacy
/aaaPrivacyaa

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/(.*)Privacy(.*)', function(req, res) {
    res.render('privacy', {'isPrivacy': true});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: "the following code still gets me 404 on valid examples"... such as?

Comment: edited the original with examples